# UITableview - tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: method not working properly?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my application i am using UITableview. In that delegate method didselectrow if i done any operation cant happen just.

For example i have 3 rows in tableview

if i select 1 row (indexPath.row==0)  nothing will happen

if again select 2 row (indexPath.row==1) now it is Logging in console indexPath.row ==0 which is previous value.

if again select 1 row then its logging its previous value indexPath.row=1.

Why this going like .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

       CustomerInfoViewController *customer = [[EquipmentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomerInfoViewController" bundle:nil];

    EquipmentViewController *equpment = [[EquipmentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EquipmentViewController" bundle:nil];

    ContactsViewController *contacts = [[ContactsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ContactsViewController" bundle:nil];

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {

        NSLog(@"one %d",indexPath.row);
        [detailsView addSubview:customer.view];
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {

         NSLog(@"two %d",indexPath.row);
        [detailsView addSubview:equpment.view];
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 2)
    {

         NSLog(@"three%d",indexPath.row);
        [detailsView addSubview:contacts.view];
    }
}
```

Please anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some actual code may be?

Comment: Seems to be logically correct. Maybe pull the initializations into the if-statements. Could it have something to do with the sections? Maybe do `NSLog(@"%d %d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);` to see if the function does not get called or your code is simply wrong. You have to clear out some options to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've implemented `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method, not `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as intended

Comment: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` used to be added by default to the UITableViewController class, but now it's replaced by `prepareForSegue:`, annoyingly. This also means a lot of people don't notice the tiny `De` in the method name and use the wrong method.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong method implementation as Vladimir said. use didSelectRowAtIndexPath